# Can I unlock an Active Directory account programmatically using CFLDAP?

Tags: coldfusion, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm writing a trouble ticketing system.  I want to be able to make a button, and when I click on it, it automatically unlocks a user's windows account in Active Directory.

Is this something that can be easily done using a CFLDAP query?

I'm running Coldfusion 8.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `userAccountControl=0`

```
<cfldap 
  action="modify" 
  attributes="userAccountControl=0"
  server="yourserver"
  dn="your DN information">
```

Comment: I will try this.  However, I've noticed that the userAccountControl value for the majority of users is either 66048 or 512.  These are the most common values.  I see none with a value of 0.

Comment: @ColdFusionDude the userAccountControl field can mean many different things. See this article for more information. [How to use the UserAccountControl flags to manipulate user account properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144)

Comment: I actually found a different solution that worked.  There's an attribute called lockoutTime.  This is a value of 0 when accounts are in normal status.  A locked-out account has a larger number value.  I programmatically set this value back to zero and, voila, account unlocked.